# Does LaunchDarkly Flag value get cached?

Tags: python, launchdarkly

I am new to python using ldclient library to get value from LaunchDarkly in backend server.  Does it get cache on backend server or there is network call on every reference?

I had assumption it would be getting cached with some TTL + any LD flag changes would do push the changes or restart the connection

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is as you assumed. The SDK downloads all feature flags on initialization. Through a websocket connection, flag changes are automatically "streamed" into the SDK running in your application process.

You would typically *not* restart your application on flag changes.

Comment: Do you know if this is mentioned somewhere in the documentation? I could only find how to register a datastore (like redis) to store data. I'd like to figure out what is the latency and what if you've multiple instances running, will there be inconsistencies.

Comment: Does maybe convince the section "Plan for a large initial payload from the streaming endpoint" on this page convince you? https://docs.launchdarkly.com/sdk/concepts/getting-started

Comment: We're evaluating multiple flags for thousands of requests per second. Latency is negligible as you can believe me, decisions are taken locally in the server side SDK. Everything is stored locally.